# Optimized array efficiency

Tags: java, arrays, performance

just a little question regarding efficiency using arrays.
For example, I have

```
JButton btn_mode[] = new JButton[2];
```

Would it make sense to set the Buttontext with an String array rather then putting the text in "by hand"? Like:

```
String btnText[] = {"Mode 1", "Mode 2"};
for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
    btn_mode[i] = new JButton(btnText[i]);
}
```

Or is it - in these few amounts - better to simply go with:

```
btn_mode[0] = new JButton("Mode 1");
btn_mode[1] = new JButton("Mode 2");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "efficient", do you really mean, "fast", or did you mean, "readable".

Comment: If this is really about "speed", then it sounds like premature optimization. I highly doubt there will have so many buttons that it matters. And if it did, I'm not sure how you'd render a hundred million buttons on the screen...

Comment: By efficient I really mean fast. I know the speed in this one is pretty insignificant but just out of curiosity I want to know which one is just that 1ms faster :)

Comment: <3 the title, it's not just any ol' efficiency we're after here, it's optimized efficiency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual speed of running the code will not be at all significant in this case, so I would go with your second choice simply because it is easier to type, read, and understand.

**EDIT:** I decided to try this out. Here are the results (each the average of 1000 trials):

```
Option 1  : 1,328,909.0 nanoseconds
Option 2  : 1,096,743.0 nanoseconds
Difference:   232,166.0 nanoseconds
```

That is a .2 millisecond difference (and option 2 is faster anyway).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know! Thank you x)